# Read CString from buffer with unknown length?

Tags: c++, buffer, cstring

Let's say I have a file. I read all the bytes into an unsigned char buffer. From there I'm trying to read a c string (null terminated) without knowing it's length.

I tried the following:

```
char* Stream::ReadCString()
{
    char str[0x10000];
    int len = 0;
    char* pos = (char*)(this->buffer[this->position]);
    while(*pos != 0)
        str[len++] = *pos++;
    this->position += len+ 1;
    return str;
}
```

I thought I could fill up each char in the str array as I went through, checking if the char was null terminated or not. This is not working. Any help?

this->buffer = array of bytes
this->position = position in the array

Are there any other methods to do this? I guess I could run it by the address of the actual buffer:
`str[len++] = *(char*)(this->buffer[this->position++])` ?

**Update:**
My new function:

```
char* Stream::ReadCString()
{
    this->AdvPosition(strlen((char*)&(this->buffer[this->position])) + 1);
    return (char*)&(this->buffer[this->position]);
}
```

and calling it with:

```
printf( "String: %s\n", s.ReadCString()); //tried casting to char* as well just outputs blank string
```

Example File:
[image]

Comment: you are trying to return a local variable

Comment: correct, for example: printf("%s\n", Stream.ReadCString());

Comment: Not sure to understand, let'say your buffer is [0,0,0,'H','E','L','L',O',0] and position is 3 why you are not returning &(buffer[position]) ? and position += strlen(&buffer[position])

Comment: @Alexis I already tried that, maybe I typed it wrong. I'll give it another go.

Comment: @Alexis It will read past it now, but it won't display it for some odd reason.

Comment: Avoid the cast c in c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

class   A
{
  unsigned char buffer[4096];
  int   position;

public:
  A() : position(0)
  {
    memset(buffer, 0, 4096);
    char        *pos = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&(this->buffer[50]));
    strcpy(pos, "String");
    pos = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&(this->buffer[100]));
    strcpy(pos, "An other string");
  }

   const char *ReadString()
  {
    if (this->position != 4096)
      {
        while (std::isalpha(this->buffer[this->position]) == false && this->position != 4096)
               this->position++;
        if (this->position == 4096)
          return 0;
        void    *tmp = &(this->buffer[this->position]);
        char    *str  = static_cast<char *>(tmp);
        this->position += strlen(str);
        return (str);
      }
    return 0;
  }

};
```

The reintrepret_cast are only for the init, since you are reading from a file

```
int     main()
{
  A     test;

  std::cout << test.ReadString() << std::endl;
  std::cout << test.ReadString() << std::endl;
  std::cout << test.ReadString() << std::endl;
}
```

http://ideone.com/LcPdFD

***Edit I have changed the end of*** `ReadString()`

Comment: I attempted and failed with reinterpret_cast<char*>, what's the difference from that and regular casting anyways?

Comment: check this new version and for the cast:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used . But reinterpret_cast is a stronger cast (and closer to a cast C) than static_cast

Comment: While I Like your answer for my old method, this seems more suitable: char* Stream::ReadCString()
{
    this->AdvPosition(strlen((char*)&(this->buffer[this->position])) + 1);
    return (char*)&(this->buffer[this->position]);
} Is there a way to display the string using this method?

Comment: Your answer is basically like mine, except you don't move position but AdvPosition. If you can't display anything is that your returning the wrong adress or something like that. And you are in c++ try to avoid the use of printf :)

Comment: tbh printf is easier to use than std::cout imo haha

Comment: I figured out my problem! I'm advancing the position and then returning the address #dumbme

Answer (score 1):

str is a local c string. Any referencing pointer to str outsider the function is undefined behavior: [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior), it might or might not cause notable problem.

Comment: That explains why, now I have to find a work around for it haha

Comment: @Jakes625 If you like, haha.

Answer (score 0):

Null termination is probably the best way to go as long as you're careful, but the reason its not working for you is most likely because you are returning memory that has been allocated on the stack. This memory is going to be freed as soon as you hit the return which will therefore cause undefined behaviour. Instead, allocate your chars on the heap:

```
char* str = new char[0x10000];
```

and free the memory when the caller doesn't need it anymore.

Comment: The string in the file is already null termined. So I guess I could just get the address of the current position. I'm just having trouble displaying now.

Comment: From address of first pos to null terminator, yeah. I'm still having troubling understanding what you're trying to do :P but good luck!

Comment: I'm reading all the contents of a file and storing it in a byte array (unsigned char*) After that I begin to read the data within. Here is my file http://puu.sh/3JC0B/f69dc57519.png . I am trying to display "entry_n" and advance the position to the byte after it. I can successfully advance the position, but the string won't display with printf("%s\n", stream.ReadCString());

Answer (score 0):

It can be fixed with the following method. I was advancing the position, and then returning the address.

```
char* Stream::ReadCString()
{
    u64 str_len = strlen((char*)&(this->buffer[this->position])) + 1;
    this->AdvPosition(str_len);
    return (char*)&(this->buffer[this->position - str_len]);
}
```

Hope this helps anyone.